# How to include/ do we need to include SSL cert in Angular HTTP Api call

Tags: angular, http, ssl-certificate

I need to call an API to get a access token. Let say, a POST method at *getAccess.com/getCode*.
whenever, I try hit this API in postman, we do use a certificate attached(option available in the Postman settings) and how it will works. Now, I am developing an application in Angular, calling the same API call using Angular HttpClient from the port *localhost://4200*. Do we need to pass this certificate while making API call ? If so, how we should configure the certificate to the API call ?

At the moment, I could see Error in browser's console,

> *net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET*

Error in browser's Network tab,

> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Answer (score 0):

Certs are all handled by the server/browser. The only thing you need to care about in the Angular app is whether you hit `http://...` or `https://...`.

After that, it's up to the server config as to whether it accepts unsecured connections or not (hint: don't) and to have the cert installed and bound to the site/url.

The browser will handle arranging the connection and ensure the cert is valid, etc.

Edit:

Ok, fair enough, cert-bound comms it is.

I'll admit to cheating and will approximately pass you Chat-GPT's answer on the topic. Looks to be a simple addition to the options for your HTTP request:

```js
const cert = `-----BEGIN...`; // get your cert
const privateKey = `-----BEGIN...`; // get your key
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('...', '...')...; // probably set some headers (e.g. content type)
const params = new HttpParams().set('...', '...')...; // maybe you have some params...

const opts = {
    headers,
    params,
    httpsAgent: {
        cert,
        key: privateKey,
        passphrase: 'if you have one...'
    }
};

return this.http.post('https://your.url', {some: 'data maybe'}, opts);
```

Comment: But how we restrict calls which do not contain certificate, in android and ios they attached certificate and private key with each request, and server authorise the request if it contains valid certificate, even in asp.net HttpClientHandler is used to attach certificate (certificate.pem, certificate.key) , how we can do this in angular